# how to configure correctly a View in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is a small app that should draw different elements. On the top are the buttons to select the forms and below the drawing space. It draws but it's putting the drawing over the buttons ... so I can't access them. Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--First line of buttons -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<!--2nd line of buttons -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The main class:

```
package com.example.drawsomething;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DrawSome extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

DrawCanvas canvas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawsome);

    Button cerc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    cerc.setOnClickListener(this);
            <!-- all the other buttons-->

    View vw=findViewById(R.id.view1);

    canvas=new DrawCanvas(this);
    addContentView(canvas, vw.getLayoutParams()); // ?!? probably this is the problem
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
        canvas.getShape(DrawCanvas.CERC);
    }
<!--onClick for the rest of the buttons-->
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a margin in the LinearLayout that contains the view? Just a thought.
The reason I say this is that the LinerLayout below overlaps the button layouts in eclipse. XML viewer.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I made a project at Uni I had a similar issue. It is simply a 3D model loader, I used this XML. With this I managed to get the buttons to be in front of the model. I think you may have to do this pragmatically unfortunately.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scene2Holder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MoveDown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/MoveRight"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapdown" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MoveLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/MoveDown"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapleft" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MoveUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/MoveLeft"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MoveLeft"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapup" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ZoomOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapzoomout" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ZoomOut"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapline" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ZoomIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapzoomin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MoveRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mapright" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And achieved:

[image]

Comment: I tried to put margins, even put the hole thing in RelativeLayout, but it didn't work, so went back to LinearLayout. The interesting thing is that it shows correctly in the xml graphical layout...

Comment: Check out the edit I posted above, may be of some help. Sorry if its not.

Comment: I solved it somehow... I put the buttons down, and the view to the top. It doesn't seem normal that I could not change the Views' origin points. No matter what I did it wanted to start from the left-top corner(this is in Eclipse/xml graphical layout). the getLayoutParams() is not getting the right values from the xml. Probably it would have worked with just the code... who knows

Comment: thanks for the help, I will try to resolve it some other way when I'll have the time